# How to hide the RSS list view browser in Android

Tags: android, listview, browser, rss, hide

I am working on RSS XML saxparser. I am creating the RSS list view so that clicking on any item will open the URL. But I want to hide the RSS select list view browser.

I have RSS list view and creating new activity file also.

[See this same type of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033311/how-to-hide-the-browser-address-bar)
What can I do here?

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            String temp=PostList.get(position).getUrl();
            String temp1=PostList.get(position).getGuid();
            if(temp.contains("http://"))
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(PostList.get(position).getUrl()));
                //Intent intent = new Intent(RSSAndroidActivity.this,com.sygnet.rss.Listview.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(temp1.contains("http://"))
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(PostList.get(position).getGuid()));
                //Intent intent = new Intent(RSSAndroidActivity.this,com.sygnet.rss.Listview.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "please, it cant able to open the link for this Feed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Listview.java

```
public class Listview extends Activity{
WebView ourBrow;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    ourBrow = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);

    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());

//        ourBrow.loadUrl(siteslist.getWebsiteValue());

   //hiding the keyboard after using an EditText
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ourBrow.getWindowToken(), 0);

}
}
```

Comment: if you dont need to use web Browser, why are you using it?

Comment: @kaluwila I want to click that any item open a another window hiding the web browser

Comment: What is your requirement with web browser? if you need to display dialog you just add alert dialog in onitemclick method instead of adding new intent to load web browser.

Comment: ok kumar please tell me what you really want to do in your onitemclick methods?

Comment: @kaluwila I am working on RSS feeds list view click that feed open another Activity window hide the AddressBar of a web page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WebViewActivity extends DashBoardActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
WebView ourBrow;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview);


    ourBrow = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);

    ourBrow.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    ourBrow.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new ourViewClient());

    ourBrow.loadUrl(www.indianbloggerpost.com);

   //hiding the keyboard after using an EditText
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(ourBrow.getWindowToken(), 0);



}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't anything to do with web browser just remove it and  call to a new activity as fallows.And in this activity you must use a web view(to hide tha address bar)

**Code:**

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
       //call to new intent here
        Intent i = new Intent(yourContext,yourActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("URL", your url);// set your url
        yourContext.startActivity(i);       

       }
});
```

yourActivity.class

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_web_view);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String url= intent.getStringExtra("URL");
        WebView mWebView= (WebView )findViewById(R.id.web_view);                
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);   
    }   
}
```

layout_web_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/contact_wev_view"
    >
<WebView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/web_view"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This one is i know but what i am doing my another activity

Comment: Hide the AddressBar of a web page

Comment: ok kumar you need a web view so i have edited the answer hope  it will solve your problem